# Prototype puzzle with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I cannot understand why the following code produces 'Smith' as output, and not 'Smith Foo'. Can you please clarify why it is happening? I cannot figure out how a `childFoo` property lookup in the prototype chain finds a way to a prototype of child.

```
var parent = {};
var child = Object.create(parent); 
Object.getPrototypeOf(parent).Surname = 'Smith';  

var parentFoo = function parentFoo() {};
var childFoo = new parentFoo(); //Object.create(parentFoo);   
Object.getPrototypeOf(parentFoo).Surname = 'Smith Foo';   

console.log(childFoo.Surname);
// this outputs 'Smith' only.
```

Comment: you changed the prototype of `parentFoo` not `childFoo`

Comment: Yes, but I created childFoo with new parentFoo(). Doesn't it happen like with normal objects that root prototype of childFoo is also a root prototype of parentFoo? Even worse, I cannot find any common prototype of child and childFoo by Object.getPrototypeOf() function.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to unravel why you're doing it like this in the first place :p

Comment: `new parentFoo` does something completely different than `Object.create(parentFoo)`?!

Comment: Why exactly are you using `Object.getPrototypeOf` in your examples? Especially because `Object.getPrototypeOf(parent)` is `Object.prototype`, and you should absolutely not modifiy that.

Comment: It was out of curiosity, to learn more about prototypes. But, I answered it myself finally in a proper way. Many Tnx!

Answer (score 3):

The source of the confusion here, I think, is the difference between `getPrototypeOf(a)` and `a.prototype`.

- `a.prototype` is the prototype that will be used to create instances of `a`, like in `new a()`.
- `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` returns the prototype that *was used* to create `a`, like in `a = new AClass()`.

So, when you do `a = new AClass()`, `Object.getPrototypeOf(a)` is equal to `AClass.prototype`, the prototype that was used to create `a`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(parent).Surname = 'Smith';
```

Here, `getPrototypeOf` returns the prototype used to create `{}`, which is `Object.prototype`. This line is equivalent to `Object.prototype.Surname = 'Smith'`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(parentFoo).Surname = 'Smith Foo';
```

Here, `getPrototypeOf` returns the prototype used to create `parentFoo`, which is a `function(){}`: The return value is `Function.prototype`. This line is equivalent to `Function.prototype.Surname = 'Smith Foo'`.

```
console.log(childFoo.Surname);
```

`childFoo` is an instance of `parentFoo`, but `parentFoo.prototype` was not modified, so it is an empty object (except for builtins). Thus, `childFoo.Surname` goes up the prototype chain, ending up at `Object.prototype`—the root that all JS objects inherit from. That's where it finds the `Surname` property that you defined earlier, `'Smith'`.

And if you do `(function () {}).Surname`, you'll see the `'Smith Foo'` string, because it was defined on `Function.prototype`.

(This can be a really tricky part of JS to wrap your head around, so I hope that made sense!)

Answer (score 0):

You did change the prototype of the Object object from which every object inherits (unless explicitly specified) with this line of code:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(parent).Surname = 'Smith';
```

Here we can see the devtools which shows that you to a property Surname with the value of Smith on the Object prototype.

[image]

Then with the following line of code :

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(parentFoo).Surname = 'Smith Foo';
```

You put the string 'Smith Foo' as a surname property on the function prototype. Here is how this looks in the chrome devtools:

[image]

Here is what you should do to get your desired result:

```js
var parent = {};
var child = Object.create(parent);
Object.getPrototypeOf(parent).Surname = 'Smith';

var parentFoo = function parentFoo() {};
var childFoo = new parentFoo(); //Object.create(parentFoo);   
// change parentFoo to childFoo
Object.getPrototypeOf(childFoo).Surname = 'Smith Foo';

console.log(childFoo.Surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer:

```js
function parentFoo() {};
var childFoo = new parentFoo(); //Object.create(parentFoo);   

parentFoo.__proto__.Surname = 'Smith Foo';   
console.log(childFoo.Surname);
console.log(parentFoo.__proto__);

parentFoo.__proto__.__proto__.Surname = 'Smith Foo';   
console.log(childFoo.Surname);
console.log(parentFoo.__proto__.__proto__);
```

Here is what I found:

1. When using directly constructor function and 'new' keyword, your new object's immediate prototype will be special function prototype

   - and next one in the chain will be the special common object prototype.
2. When using directly constructor function and 'new' keyword, your new object's immediate prototype will be special function prototype

   - and that prototype has nothing to do with prototype of function itself.

I hope I got it right this time :) Thank you all for helping out!